# How to cast a specific song programatically with Cast Audio

Tags: chromecast

I'd like to hook up a [bttn](https://bt.tn/) such that when that button is pressed, a specific song is played through my speakers using the new Chromecast Audio. I couldn't find documentation for a REST API that would allow me to accomplish this.

Is there any direct hookup that would be possible such that I can call some REST API to play audio through Cast Audio?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single rest apis to do so; the process of casting a media, using the Cast SDK, amounts to starting a discovery, selecting (connecting to) a device, setting up the so-called RemoteMediaPlayer and then loading a media. There is plenty of documentation on our [Cast documentation site](https://developers.google.com/cast/) that helps you follow and implement the above steps, along with a good number of [sample apps](https://github.com/googlecast).